# I'm trying to manipulate a simple props in React but it gives me an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators

```
let num = arr.filter(item => item == n).length;

if(num < this.props.amount){
  return alert(`${this.state.number} has had ${++num} drinks`);
//line below is the manipulation of props issue
}else if( num == this.props.amount - 1){
  return alert(`${this.state.number} has had ${this.state.number}, cut them off`);
}else if( num > this.props.amount){
  return alert(`${this.state.number} is all done drinking`)
}
```

I am just passing a simple props from the parent component. I am expecting 6, and I received six as the props. But then as I tried to make it so that the zero based array system doesn't play a part in the amount of drinks a person can have, I cannot use an operator to minus one off the props so basically the array would start at 1.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @yabna what issue exactly? `if( num == (this.props.amount - 1))`,its precedence issue

Comment: message: 'The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.'

Comment: sounds like `this.props.amount` is a string, and you need an integer to perform the minus operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `this.props.amount` is a string, and you need it to be an integer to perform the "minus" arithmetic operation. Other cases don't throw an error because in js `>` operator is valid for strings as well as integers.

The right solution then is to make sure that the props is of type integer.You can also convert the string into integer like so: `parseInt("10")`. Maybe something like:

```
const amount = parseInt(this.props.amount)
if(num < amount){
  return alert(`${this.state.number} has had ${++num} drinks`);
}else if( num == amount - 1){
  return alert(`${this.state.number} has had ${this.state.number}, cut them off`);
}else if( num > amount){
  return alert(`${this.state.number} is all done drinking`)
}
```